# Why doesn't Vue detect the variable value change immediately?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I have a method that gets data from the backend, and set my data variable to the data that's coming from the backend. I call the method inside the onMounted vue method. But when I display the data in my component it's empty and the length is 0. Strange enough, if I made any changes to the component the data displays correctly and the length changes to the correct length.

here is my code:

```
<script setup>
 import SearchBar from '@/Components/Admin/SearchBar.vue';

 import {onMounted, reactive} from 'vue'

 import moment from 'moment'

 let data = [];
 
 onMounted(() => {

    getBreeders();

})

 const getBreeders = () => {

    axios.get(route('tagsmodal.breeders')).then(response=>{

        data = response.data;
        console.log(data);

    })
 }
```

and the component:

```
{{ 'the length is '+data.length  }}

<div class="table-view" id="entityTableView">
<table class=" fullwidth">
    <thead>
       <tr>
            <th scope="col" data-attribute="title" class="orderable">Title</th>
            <th scope="col" data-attribute="postDate" class="ordered asc">Post Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="Tbody" >
        <tr v-for="(entity,index) in data" :key="entity.id" >
            <td> {{entity.name}} </td>
            <td> {{ moment(String( entity.created_at)).format('YYYY-MM-DD') }} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

the data length is always zero, and no data is displayed until I made some change to the component

Comment: [Here](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html) you can find everything about how Vue reactivity works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to turn `data` into a ref, so that Vue can detect changes to it:

```
import {ref} from 'vue'
const data = ref([])
```

In your `getBreeders()` method, you then assign the fetched data to the ref's value:

```
const getBreeders = async() => {
    const response = await axios.get(route('tagsmodal.breeders'))
    data.value = response.data;
}
```

And that should be all